# Is there a function in 3 variables that cannot be expressed as an expression of functions in 2 variables?

Tags: calculus

Is there a function $f$ in 3 variables that cannot be expressed as an expression of functions in 2 variables? E.g. given $f(x,y,z)$ there are no functions $r,s,t,u,v$ such that

$$f(x,y,z) = v(u(r(x, y), s(x, z)), t(y, z))$$

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively where did you find this problem, and what is the context behind it? Did you come up with it? Do you have any backround knowledge relevant to the problem?

Comment: $v=f,r(x, y)=x, s(x, z)=z, t(y, z)=y, U(a,b,c)=(a,c,b)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm: To be $ v = f $ one variable of $f$ must be constant?

Comment: @C-RAM: Out of general interest I was trying to find such a function but could not find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such *continuous* function in any (finite) number of variables: see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov–Arnold_representation_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold_representation_theorem).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the answer I was looking for. Is the general idea that for a continuous function there is a linear approximation at each point?

Comment: @hpc64 But you didn't mention continuity in the question.